# How to configure Drush launcher on mac sierra?

Tags: drush, ssh

I´ve installed drush on my mac sierra following the instructions from http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ but when i try run a command drush, this indicate the next instruction:

```
The Drush launcher could not find a Drupal site to operate on. Please do *one* of the following:
    - Navigate to any where within your Drupal project and try again.
    - Add --root=/path/to/drupal so Drush knows where your site is located.
```

[image]
I am new in drush and I not understand this instruction. Is needed create a new file?? what´s the name? what is the code that content this file?

Maybe I need to modify any file on my mac???  what can I do to run drush from my drupal sites?

Comment: "Navigate to any where within your Drupal project" means that you, in the terminal where you are trying to run Drush, should move to the directory where you have your Drupal files. It helps if you run `drush status` and report the output (above) if you still are unsure.

Comment: Hi hansfn! thank you, I´ve try from my project folder, but the response is the same. See the screen in https://snag.gy/E417aC.jpg

Comment: To be 100% sure: Are you inside your Drupal folder - for example inside the core folder? And try `drush -d status` to get some more information.